# MYSQL error 1728: mysql.user corrupted

Tags: mysql, corrupt

I'm totally new to MySQL, so my problem can be quite basic and I just don't know it.

I started using MySQL for my Python project and after multiple problems with installing it I finally got it working on my terminal. However, joy ended quickly - I can't neither create nor edit any user account, because of this message

> ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is probably
>   corrupted

My MySQL is installed via brew. I tried to kill all processes and start again, it didn't work. That's my mysql.user table if it's helpful in some way:

[image: mysql.user]

Edit1: I tried mysql_upgrade, and it changed to

> ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45,
>   found 48. The table is probably corrupted

Comment: Similar problem. `Column count of mysql.user is wrong.` Deleted all my databases, removed brew, reinstalled, problem still occurs.